# RecyclerView horizontal wrap_content max size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView (image below) and I have some content (a picture and some text) loading from an API. I'd like all the rows to be exactly the same height, but the text could vary wildly in length. So the yellow box should be bigger to match the green box which has more text. If that makes sense?

[image: picture A]

Currently, I'm using a LinearLayoutManager set to Horizontal, but I've also tested with a GridLayoutManager with 1 row which produces the same effect.

I'm also using setAutoMeasureEnabled to true.

1. Is there a simple way to do this with a RecyclerView?
2. If not, how would be best to calculate the height and send it down to each ViewHolder?

Thank you,

As requested:

my initialisation which is in the MainActivity onCreate:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    setUpSomeData();

    TopFilmsCard card1 = (TopFilmsCard)cards.get(0);
    mAdapter = new FilmsAdapter(card1.getFilms());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

FilmsAdapter

```
 private class FilmsAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilmsCardHolder> {

    private List<Film> films;

    public FilmsAdapter(List<Film> films) {
        this.films = films;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.holder_top_films;
    }

    @Override
    public FilmsCardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        return new FilmsCardHolder(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.holder_film, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FilmsCardHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindCard(films.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return films.size();
    }
}
```

FilmsCardHolder

public class FilmsCardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
public FilmsCardHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}


public void bindCard(Film film) {

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutFilm);
    TextView lblFilm = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblFilmName);
    ImageView imgPicture = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPicture);

    layout.setBackgroundResource(film.getColor());
    lblFilm.setText(film.getName());
    imgPicture.setImageResource(film.getPicture());


}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#CCD1D9"/>
```

holder_film

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layoutFilm"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#5D9CEC">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblFilmName"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:textSize="22sp"/>

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imgPicture"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      />
```

Comment: share your viewholder xml file, and your code related to initializing and setting the adapterplease

Comment: added, a lot of is exactly the same as described in https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html though - thank you

Comment: Try making the holder height match_parent and the recyclerview height wrap content. That might work

Comment: @howdoidothis In this case, it will cover the whole screen.

Comment: It's a bit unusual case. During binding, you can store the (so far) max value of rows in a variable in the adapter, and whenever you face a `TextView` with more rows, you `notifyDataSetChanged` and redraw the previous items with extra blank rows in their `TextView` (according to this variable). It's not very efficient, but might fit the logic you need.

Comment: You can perhaps also do what @NeriaNachum said on an invisible TextView with the same height of an recyclerview item before you populate your recyclerview.
This way at least you'll avoid redrawing the recycler view holders O(n^2) times, but only draw the textview O(n) times.